# mmap /dev/fb0 fails with "Invalid argument"

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, framebuffer

I have an embedded system and want to use `/dev/fb0` directly. As a first test, I use some code based on example-code found [everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722301/writing-to-frame-buffer) [in](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.1/qtopiacore-testingframebuffer.html) [the net](http://www.redhat.com/archives/redhat-install-list/2011-January/msg00012.html) [and SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996777/paint-pixels-to-screen-via-linux-framebuffer). Opening succeeds, also `fstat` and similar. But `mmap` fails with EINVAL.

Source:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/fb.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

int main() {
    int fbfd = 0;

    struct fb_var_screeninfo vinfo;
    struct fb_fix_screeninfo finfo;
    long int screensize = 0;
    char *fbp = 0;
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    long int location = 0;

    // Open the file for reading and writing
    fbfd = open("/dev/fb0", O_RDWR);
    if (fbfd == -1) {
        perror("Error: cannot open framebuffer device");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("The framebuffer device was opened successfully.\n");

    struct stat stat;
    fstat(fbfd, &stat);
    printf("/dev/mem -> size: %u blksize: %u blkcnt: %u\n", 
            stat.st_size, stat.st_blksize, stat.st_blocks);

    // Get fixed screen information
    if (ioctl(fbfd, FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO, &finfo) == -1) {
        perror("Error reading fixed information");
        exit(2);
    }

    // Get variable screen information
    if (ioctl(fbfd, FBIOGET_VSCREENINFO, &vinfo) == -1) {
        perror("Error reading variable information");
        exit(3);
    }

    printf("%dx%d, %dbpp\n", vinfo.xres, vinfo.yres, vinfo.bits_per_pixel);

    // Figure out the size of the screen in bytes
    screensize = vinfo.xres * vinfo.yres * vinfo.bits_per_pixel / 8;
    const int PADDING = 4096;
    int mmapsize = (screensize + PADDING - 1) & ~(PADDING-1);

    // Map the device to memory
    fbp = (char *)mmap(0, mmapsize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fbfd, 0);
    if ((int)fbp == -1) {
        perror("Error: failed to map framebuffer device to memory");
        exit(4);
    }
    printf("The framebuffer device was mapped to memory successfully.\n");

    munmap(fbp, screensize);
    close(fbfd);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
The framebuffer device was opened successfully.
/dev/mem -> size: 0 blksize: 4096 blkcnt: 0
640x480, 4bpp
Error: failed to map framebuffer device to memory: Invalid argument
```

strace:

```
...
open("/dev/fb0", O_RDWR)                = 3
write(1, "The framebuffer device was opene"..., 48The framebuffer device was opened successfully.
) = 48
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0640, st_rdev=makedev(29, 0), ...}) = 0
write(1, "/dev/mem -> size: 0 blksize: 409"..., 44/dev/mem -> size: 0 blksize: 4096 blkcnt: 0
) = 44
ioctl(3, FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO or FBIOPUT_CONTRAST, 0xbfca6564) = 0
ioctl(3, FBIOGET_VSCREENINFO, 0xbfca6600) = 0
write(1, "640x480, 4bpp\n", 14640x480, 4bpp
)         = 14
old_mmap(NULL, 155648, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, 3, 0) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
write(2, "Error: failed to map framebuffer"..., 49Error: failed to map framebuffer device to memory) = 49
write(2, ": ", 2: )                       = 2
write(2, "Invalid argument", 16Invalid argument)        = 16
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
```

The boot-screen with console and tux is visible. And `cat /dev/urandom > /dev/fb0` fills the screen with noise. The pagesize is 4096 on the system (`getconf PAGESIZE). So, 155648 (0x26000) is a multiple. Offset and pointer are both zero. Mapping and filemode are both RW .. what am I missing?

This is for an embedded device build with uClibc and busybox running a single application and I have to port it from an ancient kernel. There is code for linedrawing and such and no need for multiprocessing/ windowing .. please no hints to directfb ;).

Comment: Do you know for a fact that your framebuffer driver supports mapping?  Can you even read() from the framebuffer progressively (simple to test with dd)?

Comment: No. Its just a vanilla kernel and "standard"-x86-hardware. How can I check?

Comment: Perhaps you could check the validity of your mmap code against an actual file instead?  As for the framebuffer, you might need to look at the source of its driver.

Comment: I have tested with /dev/mem - no problem (first MB is still valid without special kernel options). I hopped I could avoid digging deep into kernel sources :/

Comment: I am not exactly sure about your problem, I once had an error like dev/fb0 is not accessible. I was not removing my sd card properly from the computer after copying the linux image in it ( In the BOOT partition of it). The SD card should safely removed from the computer. So I can suggest that just follow all the basic steps properly.

Answer (score 4):

The kernel driver that presents the `framebuffer` doesn't support the legacy direct `mmap()` of the `framebuffer` device; you need to use the newer `DRM` and `KMS` interface.

Comment: And how would I do that?

Comment: It seems that the kernel driver **does** support `mmap()`, however it refuses to map more than N bytes of it at a time (seems to differ by hardware, but I've seen the maximum be around 3MB-8MB), which makes it not very useful for direct graphics output.

Comment: Actually, I was only able to replicate the "invalid argument" error by trying to mmap more than X times Y times bpp bytes (for 1280x800,32bpp, that's 8294400 bytes). So for anyone running into this, make sure you're not trying to map more than the size of the framebuffer.