# Writing directly to the screen from an x86_64 Linux machine

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, video-memory

I am using a Linux x86_64 machine. Is it possible to write to the screen from my user space application (`C` or `assembly`) without using the standard library functions or system calls? I know this is possible in the real mode or in DOS with a pointer to the video memory `0XB800`

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: You can make some system calls to map the framebuffer into your process's memory.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_framebuffer.  There's probably a library wrapper to help set things up, but once that's done you can run plain store instructions to directly draw pixels into video RAM, I think.  (Of course that only works if you program is running on a console; under X11 or Wayland it's a totally different interface (if it's possible at all) to memory-map a pixmap for a window.

Comment: DOS did not have a display manager running. All graphics was done by each program.  The closest you can get with Xorg running is to create a full-screen window using calls to the display manager, then read and write to that window.

Comment: @PeterCordes you can't mmap FB: see [_mmap /dev/fb0 fails with “Invalid argument”_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22915778/673852)

Comment: @Ruslan: thanks, yeah it's been a while since I even ran anything other than an X server.  I thought it was possible somehow but forgot which kernel API / driver let you map video memory.  SVGAlib might be a good choice to hide the lowest-level setup details, if it lets you map VGA memory.

Comment: As Raymond Chen is fond of saying, imagine two programs would do that.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev that's as easy as two programs `write`ing to `/dev/fb0`. The resolution is exactly the same (failure to open an already open device, I suppose; didn't check actual behavior).

Comment: I meant as desired by the OP, *sans* kernel's involvement.