# Writing to /dev/fb0 using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, v4l2

So am a bit confused about doing an memcopy to a mapped frame buffer device (ex. /dev/fb0) hwne using OpenCV.

For example, looking at one of the OpenCV capture functions for both C and C++:

```
C: IplImage* cvQueryFrame(CvCapture* capture) 
C++: bool VideoCapture::read(Mat& image)
```

it looks like the image data is stored in the Matrix Structure (MAT) for C++ and the CvCapture black-box structure for C. There are plenty of examples of how to use these on the web, so am good there.

However, I haven't found any good (consistent) code snippets that show how to take the image data stored in those structures and copy it to the frame buffer.

Does anyone know or have examples of the conversions needed to this?

(Noob to both Linux and OpenCV)

Comment: why are you trying to write to the framebuffer?

Comment: I have an embedded board, with a minimal Linux image - no desktop etc. I have a USB DisplayLink monitor attached. Eventually I want to do some video processing but for right now I am just trying to display images from the webcam.

Comment: If you have a better way of doing this, I am open to new ideas

Comment: Would a better way to do this be using the DRM in the kernel?

Comment: no; it would be better to move away to a high-level abstraction.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless whether this approach is considered good or not, you can do it like this (only supports some combinations of pixel formats):

```
/**
 * @file fbwrite_video.cpp
 * Displays OpenCV video on framebuffer.
 * Compile with
 * g++ -o fbwrite_video -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc fbwrite_video.cpp
 *
 * Contains code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722301/writing-to-frame-buffer
 */

#include <iostream> // for std::cerr
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>  // for cv::cvtColor
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp> // for cv::VideoCapture
#include <fstream> // for std::ofstream
#include <boost/timer/timer.hpp> // for boost::timer::cpu_timer

// this is C :/
#include <stdint.h> // for uint32_t
#include <sys/ioctl.h> // for ioctl
#include <linux/fb.h> // for fb_
#include <fcntl.h> // for O_RDWR
struct framebuffer_info { 
    uint32_t bits_per_pixel; uint32_t xres_virtual; 
};
struct framebuffer_info get_framebuffer_info(const char* framebuffer_device_path) {
    struct framebuffer_info info;
    struct fb_var_screeninfo screen_info;
    int fd = -1;
    fd = open(framebuffer_device_path, O_RDWR);
    if (fd >= 0) {
        if (!ioctl(fd, FBIOGET_VSCREENINFO, &screen_info)) {
            info.xres_virtual = screen_info.xres_virtual;
            info.bits_per_pixel = screen_info.bits_per_pixel;
        }
    }
    return info;
};
// C ends here

int main(int, char**) {
    const int frame_width = 320;
    const int frame_height = 240;
    const int frame_rate = 10;
    framebuffer_info fb_info = get_framebuffer_info("/dev/fb0");
    cv::VideoCapture cap(0);
    if(!cap.isOpened()) {
        std::cerr << "Could not open video device." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Successfully opened video device." << std::endl;
        cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,frame_width);
        cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,frame_height);
        cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS,frame_rate);
        std::ofstream ofs("/dev/fb0");
        cv::Mat frame;
        while (true) {
            cap >> frame;
            if (frame.depth() != CV_8U) {
                std::cerr << "Not 8 bits per pixel and channel." << std::endl;
            } else if (frame.channels() != 3) {
                std::cerr << "Not 3 channels." << std::endl;
            } else {
                // 3 Channels (assumed BGR), 8 Bit per Pixel and Channel
                int framebuffer_width = fb_info.xres_virtual;
                int framebuffer_depth = fb_info.bits_per_pixel;
                cv::Size2f frame_size = frame.size();
                cv::Mat framebuffer_compat;
                switch (framebuffer_depth) {
                    case 16:
                        cv::cvtColor(frame, framebuffer_compat, cv::COLOR_BGR2BGR565);
                        for (int y = 0; y < frame_size.height ; y++) {
                            ofs.seekp(y*framebuffer_width*2);
                            ofs.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(framebuffer_compat.ptr(y)),frame_size.width*2);
                        }
                    break;
                    case 32: {
                            std::vector<cv::Mat> split_bgr;
                            cv::split(frame, split_bgr);
                            split_bgr.push_back(cv::Mat(frame_size,CV_8UC1,cv::Scalar(255)));
                            cv::merge(split_bgr, framebuffer_compat);
                            for (int y = 0; y < frame_size.height ; y++) {
                                ofs.seekp(y*framebuffer_width*4);
                                ofs.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(framebuffer_compat.ptr(y)),frame_size.width*4);
                            }
                        } break;
                    default:
                        std::cerr << "Unsupported depth of framebuffer." << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to access the raw framebuffer device directly.

Instead use some intermediate library that abstracts away that actual output device, e.g. [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/) (I'm not entirely sure whether *SDL2* supports framebuffers (chances are it [does not](http://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?p=42412&sid=8cf1d6c83d4d73fe6cfbb7cbb16b3d28)), but *SDL1* definitely does.

Comment: Is that an over-generalization? Is there some reason that would be recommended for an embedded system like a Raspberry Pi running Raspian withno desktop (e.g.no X11) or contenders, for a dedicated application...  and only one graphics device? That surely must be an exception? Why would I want the overhead of abstraction in that case?